# How can I use macroexpand-1 from a source file instead of the REPL

Tags: clojure

What is the proper way to use `macroexpand-1` for testing Clojure macros when not working at the REPL?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your expressions outside of the `deftest` are being run at compile time, while `*ns*` is bound, and inside of a `deftest` they are being run later, at runtime, where `*ns*` is not bound.

Why does this matter? Because `macroexpand` needs to resolve the symbol `iiinc` in the current namespace in order to decide if it's a macro or not, and to find its definition if it is a macro, in order to call it. So, you see your `macroexpand` working at compile time but not at runtime.

What is the solution? Surely not to run your tests at compile time! Instead, you should properly namespace-qualify your forms, so that they do not depend on the compile-time convenience of `*ns*`. You could do this by hand, by writing

```
(deftest t-stuff
  (println "(macroexpand-1 '(my.ns/iiinc 2))  =>" (macroexpand-1 '(my.ns/iiinc 2)))))
```

However, the right solution is to do what you should *always* do when quoting forms that are intended for later evaluation, just as when you write a macro: use syntax-quote, not regular quote. This way the compiler figures out the intended namespace for you at compile time, and inserts it in the form so that it's still there at runtime:

```
(deftest t-stuff
  (println "(macroexpand-1 `(iiinc 2))  =>" (macroexpand-1 `(iiinc 2)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to test a macro that adds 3 to any value:

```
(defmacro iiinc [x]
  `(+ 3 ~x))
```

Rather than working at the REPL, I usually prefer to use my favorite text editor/IDE to develop code, and use [the `lein test-refresh` plugin](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) to continually run my unit tests. However, this doesn't work when trying to use `macroexpand-1` to iteratively develop a new macro.

The problem seems to be some conflict between `macroexpand-1` and the `deftest` macro.  So, the solution is to avoid using `macroexpand-1` inside of a `(deftest ...)` form. However, it works great outside of `deftest`, even if it is still in the unit test source file.  Here's an example:

```
; source file tst.clj.core

(newline)
(println "This works when not in (deftest ...)")
(println "(macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2))  =>" (macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2)))
    
(deftest t-stuff
  (newline)
  (println "But it is broken inside (deftest ...)")
  (println "(macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2))  =>" (macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2)))

  (newline)
  (println "However, we can use the macro itself fine in our tests")
  (println "  (iiinc 2) =>" (iiinc 2))
  (is (= 5 (iiinc 2))))  ; unit test works fine
```

The results of the above are:

```
This works when not in (deftest ...)
(macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2))  => (clojure.core/+ 3 2)

Testing tst.clj.core

But it is broken inside (deftest ...)
(macroexpand-1 '(iiinc 2))  => (iiinc 2)

However, we can use the macro itself fine in our tests
  (iiinc 2) => 5

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

---

### Postscript

Please see the following answer for a
more complete discussion of how to write a macro in Clojure:

[How do I write a Clojure threading macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro)

Comment: A good answer, but I think some of this content should be in the question itself, because it explains what you're trying to do that's not working. Without the context of this answer, nobody else could answer your very abbreviated question.

Comment: Looking back at this four years later, I now think the entire answer should be moved into the question. You don't provide any answer to your question "How do I test a macro with macroexpand?"; you just conclude that it doesn't work. It's very thorough, as a question, and I think my answer provides a good answer to it, I just don't see how any of this is an answer.