# Is there a significant performance difference between running `explain-data` and `valid?`

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is there a significant performance difference between running `explain-data` and `valid?`.

For example, I have this code

```
(let [is-valid? (spec/valid? ::SpecitySpec the-map)
      _ (when-not is-valid?
          (throw (ex-info "the-map doesn't match spec"
                          {:explain-data (spec/explain-data ::SpecitySpec the-map)})))])
```

In the case of a happy path, then it will only run `valid?`.

Though, for brevity, my preference would be:

```
(let [explain-data (spec/explain-data ::SpecitySpec the-map)
      _ (when explain-data
          (throw (ex-info "the-map doesn't match spec"
                          {:explain-data explain-data}))
```

However, if there's a bigger performance hit to `explain-data`, then I think the first example would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer your own question!

Just use `clojure.core/time` to measure the execution speed of the two options.  If you really want the 2nd version, you could easily write a macro to convert the code from #2 into the code for #1.  A good name might be `validate-spec` or similar.

You may also be interested in this question about [writing macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro/60213454#60213454).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in Clojurians Slack #clojure-spec channel, and got an [answer from Alex Miller](https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/C1B1BB2Q3/p1586971117125800).  Here is what he said:

> They both ultimately call the same function so I would expect perf to
>   be pretty similar right now. we have considered fast-pathing a
>   separate valid? path in spec 2 though and I would expect that to be
>   the faster option.
>
> The big differences are that a) with valid?, you can fail fast and b)
>   with explain, you have to track a lot of additional info and
>   accumulate it for reporting