# How to fix this macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm trying to convert my macro to the following expansion:

```
(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
 :some-name
 (fn [db [foo bar]]
   (assoc db :foo foo :bar bar)
   ))
```

and I have this so far

```
(defmacro db-event 
  [name params & body]
  `(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
    ~name
    (fn [db ~params]
      ~@body)))
```

But this doesn't really work when I try with

```
(db-event :some-name [foo bar] 
  (assoc db :foo foo :bar bar))
```

I get the following:

```
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:17
 Use of undeclared Var vendo.macros/foo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:21
 Use of undeclared Var vendo.macros/bar
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:33
 Use of undeclared Var vendo.macros/db
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:41
 Use of undeclared Var vendo.macros/foo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:50
 Use of undeclared Var vendo.macros/bar
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


(re-frame.core/reg-event-db {:foo nil, :bar nil} (cljs.core/fn [vendo.macros/my-db nil]))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably it would be a good idea for the macro to also accept the symbol used for `db` parameter.

Comment: there is at least one problem i can see: `db` gets namespaced, so you would need to do something like : `(fn [~'db ~params] ~@body)`

Answer (score 0):

Start off by reviewing [this answer on macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro/60213454#60213454).  Then build it up slowly.

Not that, since `db` is only ever used inside your constructed function, it doesn't need to be a parameter to the macro call.

First iteration:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn db-event-impl
  [[name params]]
  (spyx name)
  (spyx params)
  (let [result `(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
                  )
        ]
    (spyx-pretty result))
  )

(dotest
  (db-event-impl (quote [:some-name [foo bar]]))
  )
```

with result:

```
name => :some-name
params => [foo bar]
result => 
(re-frame.core/reg-event-db)
```

add some more code:

```
(defn db-event-impl
  [[name params]]
  (spyx name)
  (spyx params)
  (let [result `(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
                  ~name
                  (fn [~'db ; trick to prevent namespacing of `db`
                       ~params ]
                    (assoc ~'db )

                    ) ) ]
    (spyx-pretty result)) )
```

and get:

```
name => :some-name
params => [foo bar]
result => 
(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
 :some-name
 (clojure.core/fn [db [foo bar]] (clojure.core/assoc db)))
```

Add some more for the `assoc` part:

```
  (let [assoc-form (->list
                     (apply glue
                       (quote [assoc db])
                       (forv [param params]
                         [(->kw param) param])))
        result     `(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
                      ~name
                      (fn [~'db ; trick to prevent namespacing of `db`
                           ~params]
                        (assoc ~'db)

                        ))]
    (spyx assoc-form)
    (spyx-pretty result)))
```

with result:

```
name => :some-name
params => [foo bar]
assoc-form => (assoc db :foo foo :bar bar)
result => 
(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
 :some-name
 (clojure.core/fn [db [foo bar]] (clojure.core/assoc db)))
```

Then put it all together:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn db-event-impl
  [[name params]]
  (let [assoc-form (->list
                     (apply glue
                       (quote [assoc db])
                       (forv [param params]
                         [(->kw param) param])))
        result     `(re-frame.core/reg-event-db
                      ~name
                      (fn [~'db ; trick to prevent namespacing of `db`
                           ~params]
                        ~assoc-form))]
    result))

(defmacro db-event
  [& args]
  (db-event-impl args))

(dotest
  (let [expected (quote
                   (re-frame.core/reg-event-db
                     :some-name
                     (clojure.core/fn [db [foo bar]]
                       (assoc db :foo foo :bar bar))))]
    (is= expected
      (db-event-impl (quote [:some-name [foo bar]])))))
```