# Why does the macroexpand does not print the results of defmacro?

Tags: clojure

I am a newbie to **Clojure** and currently trying to invoke a simple macro using `defmacro` and `macroexpand`.

```
(ns tutorial.core
  (:gen-class)) ; namespace

(defn -main [& args]
    
      (defmacro Simple [] (println "Hello"))
      (macroexpand '(Simple))
    
    )
```

Is there something I have missed? it seems the program runs without any problems but the results are not coming out as expected.

I expect the results to print out as `Hello`, but no outputs result from this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface:

Please see this past question for an overview of [the best way to write a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro) (IMHO).

---

### Answer:

You shouldn't define the macro in the `main` function.  Try this:

```
(ns demo.core)

(defmacro happy
  []
  `(println "I'm happy!"))   ; *** notice the backtick! ***

(defn -main [& args]
  (println :expanded (macroexpand '(happy)))
  (happy)
  )
```

start up a repl:

```
~/expr/demo > lein repl

demo.core=> (macroexpand '(happy))
;=> (clojure.core/println "I'm happy!")
```

and we see that it works.  Try running from the command line:

```
~/expr/demo > lein run
:expanded (happy)   ;  <= ***** OOOPS!  *****
I'm happy!
```

Try changing the single-quote into a syntax-quote (aka backtick), then run:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println :expanded (macroexpand `(happy)))
  (happy))

~/expr/demo > lein run
:expanded (clojure.core/println I'm happy!)
I'm happy!
```

The explanation is that the syntax-quote will fully-qualify the Var `happy` => `demo.core/happy` (you can see the same effect on the `println` Var inside of the `happy` macro itself because of that syntax-quote).  This allows the macroexpand to work properly.  Compare with a single-quote:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println :expanded (macroexpand '(demo.core/happy)))
  (happy))

~/expr/demo > lein run
:expanded (clojure.core/println I'm happy!)
I'm happy!
```

The cause of this behavior is that, in the REPL, we see from the prompt that we are in the `demo.core` namespace, so `happy` is resolved as `demo.core/happy`.  When we use `lein run`, however, observe:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println *ns*)
  (println (ns-name *ns*)))
```

with result:

```
~/expr/demo > lein run
*ns*             => #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0xb625b00 "user"]
(ns-name *ns*)   => user
```

and we see that the `*ns*` is set to the `user` namespace and `happy` cannot be resolved to the Var `demo.core/happy` unless we fully qualify it either manually or using `syntax-quote` in the code.

---

You can find a [list of documentation here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).  Be sure especially to study the Clojure CheatSheet.

For macros, the book [Mastering Clojure Macros](https://pragprog.com/titles/cjclojure/) is also good.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro function doesn't return code, but does the printing immediately. This is very bad style as it has unforeseen consequences.

If you were to use this is a function:

```
(defn hello [] (Simple))
```

It prints "Hello" when the function is created. The code being inserted in the function is the result fo `println` which is `nil`, thus you have created this:

```
(defn hello [] nil)
```

Then if you call `hello` 3 times none of the calls will no any printing since your macro doesn't produce anything else than `nil`. If you change your macro to return structure:

```
;; The quote that makes all the difference
(defmacro Simple [] '(println "Hello"))
```

Then if will not print anything during the createion of `hello`, but the expansion would be `(println "Hello")` and the same fucntion `hello` would become:

```
(defn hello [] (println "Hello"))
```