# Why does adding metadata to a function definition work differently than other forms, in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Why does this fail:

```clj
(eval (with-meta '(fn [] 0) {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
; Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1).
; Unable to resolve symbol: overflow210 in this context
```

when none of the following fail?

```clj
(eval (with-meta '(do [] 0) {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
; 0
(eval (with-meta '(let [] 0) {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
; 0
(eval (with-meta '(if true 0 1) {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
; 0
(eval (with-meta '(println "hello") {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
; hello
; nil
```

The examples above are my attempt to find a minimal, reproducible example. I ran into this question when working on a macro, with a simplified example here:

```clj
(defmacro my-macro []
  (with-meta '(fn [] 0) {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))

(my-macro)
; Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1).
; Unable to resolve symbol: overflow156 in this context
```

while attempting to follow the model explained in this post on [testing Clojure macros](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/testing-clojure-macros/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! This was fun to dig into.

It's helpful to first start by trying to set the metadata map to something that works, and retrieve it in each of your examples:

```
(meta (eval (with-meta '(fn [] 0) {:ten 10})))
;;=> {:ten 10}
(meta (eval (with-meta '(do [] 0) {:ten 10})))
;;=> nil
(meta (eval (with-meta '(let [] 0) {:ten 10})))
;;=> nil
(meta (eval (with-meta '(if true 0 1) {:ten 10})))
;;=> nil
(meta (eval (with-meta '(println "hello") {:ten 10})))
;; printed: hello
;;=> nil
```

Hopefully this gives you some idea of what's happening here: the metadata isn't returned as part of the value of the non-`fn` forms, so it's not evaluated. We can test this hypothesis with another value that uses its metadata, like a vector:

```
(meta (eval (with-meta '[1] {:ten 10})))
;;=> {:ten 10}
```

but with a `gensym`:

```
(eval (with-meta '[1] {:stack (gensym "overflow")}))
;;=> Syntax error compiling at (tmp:localhost:35479(clj)*:25:7).
;;=> Unable to resolve symbol: overflow6261 in this context
```

You can see [where this is emitted in the Clojure compiler](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/0df3d8e2e27fb06fa53398754cac2be4878b12d1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L4125-L4126), and searching for `new MetaExpr` will show you the other places where metadata evaluation is emitted (I could see vectors, maps, sets, functions, and `reify`).

**tl,dr:**  Clojure evaluates the metadata for function forms because it attaches the evaluated metadata to the resulting function. This is also true of the data literals supported in Clojure's syntax. Any other metadata on forms is stripped away by compilation, so it doesn't get evaluated and thus doesn't cause symbol resolution errors.

Comment: Excellent exploration of the topic!

Comment: Thank you for walking through the process of how to get to the answer, I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your usage of `gensym`, not the metadata.  Observe:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (binding [*print-meta* true]
    (let [
          fn-code-plain  '(fn [] 42)
          fn-code-meta   (with-meta '(fn [] 42) {:alpha true})

          fn-code-sym-meta   (with-meta '(fn [] 42) {:alpha (gensym "dummy")})
          ]
      (prn fn-code-plain)
      (prn fn-code-meta)
\
      (prn (eval fn-code-plain))
      (prn (eval fn-code-meta))
      (newline)
      (prn fn-code-sym-meta)

      (throws? (eval fn-code-sym-meta))

      )
    ))
```

with result:

```
^{:line 7, :column 27} (fn [] 42)
^{:alpha true}         (fn [] 42)

#object[user$eval19866$fn__19867 0xac891b5 "user$eval19866$fn__19867@ac891b5"]
^{:alpha true} #object[user$eval19870$fn__19871 0x2d1ab7e0 "user$eval19870$fn__19871@2d1ab7e0"]

^{:alpha dummy19865} (fn [] 42)
```

The problem is that `eval` sees the symbol `dummy19865` and tries to resolve it.  The fact that it was created by `gensym` is irrelevant.  No problem with a keyword:

```
  fn-code-kw-meta   (with-meta '(fn [] 42) {:alpha :dummy-42})
  <snip>
  (prn fn-code-kw-meta)
  (prn (eval fn-code-kw-meta))
```

producing:

```
^{:alpha :dummy-42} (fn [] 42)
^{:alpha :dummy-42} #object[user$eval19953$fn__19954 0x13253ac7 "user$eval19953$fn__19954@13253ac7"]
```

or a symbol that is defined:

```
(def mysym "Forty-Two!")
<snip>

  fn-code-mysym-meta   (with-meta '(fn [] 42) {:alpha mysym})
  <snip>

(prn fn-code-mysym-meta)
(prn (eval fn-code-mysym-meta))
```

with result:

```
^{:alpha "Forty-Two!"} (fn [] 42)
^{:alpha "Forty-Two!"} #object[user$eval20082$fn__20083 0x24a63de5 "user$eval20082$fn__20083@24a63de5"]
```

---

### Summary:

You have demonstrated that `eval` only attempts symbol resolution of metadata for the `fn` form, but not other special forms like `do`, `let`, `if`, or with pre-existing functions such as `println`.  If you wish to explore further, you should probably inquire at the Clojure email list:

```
clojure@googlegroups.com
```

---

The above code is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: I think in my attempt to simplify the example, too much context was lost. I originally ran into this question when trying to add metadata to the output of a macro (eval was not directly involved). See my updated post for more info!

Comment: Please see the updated answer for full info.  Also, why are you using a `gensym` in the metadata?  Could you use a plain string?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Your summary at the end is a beautiful articulation of the situation at hand.

Comment: I originally encountered this after following this post: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/testing-clojure-macros/, and discovering that returning a `fn` form exhibited the problem whereas other forms didn't.

Comment: Interesting article on testing macros. I normally just test a macro for functionality, and don't write unit tests to verify expansion. Please see this answer for how I build up a macro step-by-step:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro

Comment: Thanks for that, I enjoyed reading through your linked answer! Testing macros is a fun topic that I'm still exploring... often times I feel like testing to verify expansion can dramatically shrink the space of what needs to be tested, especially when the macro is mostly for syntactic sugar (e.g. I don't need to test whether the if form works, I just need to make sure the if form is used as intended!). But I can also see how testing for functionality gets at the core of what actually matters when using the macro, and may be simpler in some cases.

Comment: The essence of the linked answer is that you build up the macro piece-by-piece, *visually* inspecting for the correct expansion as you go.