# Can I reference a macro from within a macro in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros

Clojure. Cursive. REPL. Windows 10. All up-to-date.
Here's my 'base' macro:

```
(defmacro PutProp! [Sym Val PName]
  `(reset-meta! (var ~Sym) (assoc (meta (var ~Sym)) ~PName ~Val)))
```

I have no idea if this is even correct in doing what I want to do, which is to modify **Sym**'s metadata keyname **PName** with the new **Val** value. I'm new at this and I'm SURE I've jumped into the pool at the deep end. I'm using a macro because I thought it would avoid messy variable binding issues which I don't understand in Clojure.

Then I wrote another macro to define a lot of metadata on a single call:

```
(defmacro DefMeta! [L]  ;; Given a symbol (first L), define metadata for it given in (next L).
  `(let [S (first ~@L)]     ;; The symbol we're modifying is the first element in list L.
     (map (fn [[K V]] (PutProp! S V K)) (next ~@L))))   ;; (next L) is the list of key/value pairs.
```

I'm also not sure this is what I want to write.
Working at the REPL, I define a symbol:

```
(def Sym 0)
```

Then I do a macroexpand-1 of DefMeta!:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(DefMeta! [Sym :VName :VValue]))
```

I get the following:

```
(clojure.core/let
 [thic.core/S (clojure.core/first Sym :VName :VValue)]
 (clojure.core/map
  (clojure.core/fn [[thic.core/K thic.core/V]] (thic.core/PutProp! thic.core/S thic.core/V thic.core/K))
  (clojure.core/next Sym :VName :VValue)))
```

which doesn't macro-expand the PutProp! macro.
I'm stumped. I have **four** books on Clojure programming and **none** of them mentions macro calls from within macro calls. Is it even legal? If so, how do I fully expand the inner macro so that I can see if what I've written is what I want? [...*the perennial programmer problem*...]
PS I tried `macroexpand-all` and I'm overwhelmed with the macroexpansion of EVERYTHING, even Clojure core functions.
Something less than that, please. Please?

Comment: Could you possibly add an example of the desired use-case and result?  Unless I'm missing something, `PutProp!` does not need to be a macro, and could be written as a simple function (much preferred).

Comment: Also, a small style point.  Clojure normally uses "kabob-case" like `def-meta!` for names.  CamelCase names like `DefMeta!` are normally reserved for interaction with Java classes or their Clojure cousins, records.

Comment: Why not call `macroexpand-1` on the result of the first `macroexpand-1` if you're just wanting one more level of expansion?

Comment: Thank you! The idea to macro-expand the macro-expansion was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly legal (& common) for the definition of a macro to make use of another macro.

You can see an example of the best way IMHO to build up a macro step-by-step [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro).

I don't like using the `macroexpand-*` functions. The answer in the above link uses simple helper functions with `println` and friends so you can see what is occurring one step at a time in the macro writing process.  Enjoy!

Comment: "Yes, it's legal." This was the most helpful piece of information of all. I will follow up on that link in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

> which doesn't macro-expand the PutProp! macro.

Yes, `macroexpand-1` only performs one pass of macroexpansion. The whole process of macroexpansion is a fixpoint computation where each tree is expanded until it reaches a form that cannot be expanded anymore.

You may want to use [macroexpand-all](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all)

Also, the input list in your macro is a list of expressions, and you want to take the first and next of this list at macroexpansion time.

```
(first ~@L)
```

This above expands as:

```
(clojure.core/first Sym :VName :VValue)
```

Where your in fact want only `Sym`, which is:

```
~(first L)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I've got it doing what I want now.