# How do I generate a sequence of defs based on a parameter

Tags: clojure

I can "generate" a def with a macro.

```
(defmacro my-def [my-name]
  `(def ~my-name 42))

(my-def a)

a; => 42
```

If I try to do something similar with a list

```
(defmacro my-defs [my-names]
  `(do
    ~@(for [name# my-names]
      `(def ~name# 42))))

(my-defs (a b c))

(macroexpand '(my-defs (a b c))); => (do (def a 42) (def b 42) (def c 42))
```

It works as long as I use a literal list as input. But as soon as I want to pass in a var

```
(def my-list '(a b c))

(macroexpand '(my-defs my-list)); => Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

I struggle to access the value of `my-names`. I can't use `~my-names` as it is already used in a unquote-splice (`~@`) and would lead to an "Attempt[...] to call unbound fn".

What am I missing?

Do I need to use `(var-get (resolve my-names))`?

Do macros in these cases need to "detect" if the passed argument is a literal value or a var and act accordingly in order to work for both?

Or is it idiomatic to use `eval` to avoid this?

Addressing @Alan Thompson's question "[...] why [do] you want to do this?": I have a specification (a deeply nested map) of "resources" and it would be rather handy to have a macro generate defs (records) for these resources in order to use them down the line. So I guess no reason out of the ordinary "It would DRY up things". :) At this time I found a way by wrapping `my-names` in an `eval`. The question that remains is: Is this idiomatic, or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It really helps in finding an appropriate answer. If you want to stick to just writing a macro which will create a bunch of `def` statements, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a paragraph to address your valid question. And I'll study the answer you linked.

Comment: @branch14 To address your answer why you want to do this: You say you have a deeply nested map of resources. I would traverse this map using, for instance, postwalk and construct one big map from keywords to resources (instead of generating a def for every resource): `(def resources (postwalk ...))`. Then I would simply access a resource by the key from this map: `(:my-resource resources)` (as opposed to having a `def`fed resource `my-resource`).

Comment: @Rulle Thank you for your suggestion. That is totally a route I would choose (and have done so) in other scenarios. But in this case it doesn't do the trick from an API standpoint.

Comment: @branch14 I see. If you include part of the deeply nested map of resources and some examples of how defs should be generated from that map, chances are you can get an answer that better addresses your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally you can't employ macro to generate code based on runtime value,
still your task doesn't require macro in clojure, since you can dynamically intern vars in namespaces:

```
(defn intern-vals [data]
  (doseq [[var-name var-val] data]
    (intern *ns* var-name var-val)))

user> (intern-vals {'some-val 10 'other-val 20})
;;=> nil

user> some-val
;;=> 10

user> other-val
;;=> 20
```

notice that this function interns values in the namespace it gets called from, thanks to `*ns*` dynamic var:

```
user> (ns a2)

a2> (user/intern-vals {'some-val "asd" 'other-val "xxx"})
;;=> nil

a2> some-val
;;=> "asd"

a2> user/some-val
;;=> 10
```

Comment: Thank you for your inspiring answer. I don't understand how "generally you can't employ macro to generate code based on runtime value" can be true. But apart from that I really like your means to intern vars. I can totally see how that can be useful!

Comment: I ended up using this approach, as a macro with eval caused more problems down the line. So I ditched the macro and went with dynamically interning vars. Thx again. Marking this as the correct answer because it solved my problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Macros play with symbols.  When you call your macro with "my-names", that symbol goes straight into the macro, there's no lookup of the var as there would be in a function call.  Then the macro says `(for...` and instead of a sequence there's a symbol!

As for what you should do... well, you may use `resolve` inside the macro, but then the macro will ONLY work if given a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

> Addressing @Alan Thompson's question "[...] why [do] you want to do
> this?": I have a specification (a deeply nested map) of "resources"
> and it would be rather handy to have a macro generate defs (records)
> for these resources in order to use them down the line. So I guess no
> reason out of the ordinary "It would DRY up things". :) At this time I
> found a way by wrapping my-names in an eval. The question that remains
> is: Is this idiomatic, or is there a better way?

I would make a single var that contains them all. And allow the macro caller to specify the var name they want. Thus making the macro "hygenic".

Is there any particular reason they *have* to be root vars?

The reason it doesn't work is the macro is passed the symbol `my-list`, not its value. So yes, you can `eval` it to find its value.

Considering that you are doing a `(def my-list ...)` first, why not make that the very def that declares your processed data struct? For example:

```
(def my-processed-set 
  (my-processing-macro '(a b c)))
```

or combining it

```
(defresources my-processed-resources '(a b c))
```

where `defresources` is your macro, and it binds the resultant set to the var referenced by the symbol passed in `my-processed-resources`

Then use them like `(:resource-1 my-processed-resources)`

Which brings you all the way back to just using a function.

```
(def my-processed-set 
  (my-processing-function '(a b c)))
```

data > functions > macros.