# Write clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to program a macro in clojure. The macro is called like this **(FORI from to task)** e.g. **(FORI 1 10 (println i))** and should print the numbers from 1 to 10. So far i have

```
(defmacro FORI [from to task]
  `(let [i# (range ~from ~to)]
     ~task))
```

I don´t know how do get the list i# into the (print i).

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can see a good overview of Clojure macros here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro

Answer (score 2):

You can use any symbol in hygienic forms if you unquote their quoted form:

```clj
(defmacro fori [from to task]
  `(doseq [~'i (range ~from ~to)]
      ~task))
```

So here in the expanded form, symbol `i` will be substituted without change.

Note, using fixed symbols in macros is usually not a good practice, because now `i` will shadow other vars with the same name.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Macros are hard for me as a clojure beginner.