# Clojure macros call function from macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I have this ns with a macro in it.  The annoying thing im dealing with is that the taoensso.timbre macro only works as a variadic expression `(timbre/info "a" "b" "c")`.  A list of items wont log right `(timbre/info ["a" "b" "c"])`.  Im trying to create a wrapper macro that lets the code call `(logger/info)` in the same variadic form, then process all elements, and then pass to timbre/info

```
(ns logger
  (:require [taoensso.timbre :as timbre :include-macros true])) ; a third party logger

;; A bit of pseudo code here. If you pass in a vector of args, you should get a vector of args with some changes
(defn scrub [args]
  (if (listy)
     (mapv (fn [a] (scrub args) args)
     (if (is-entry a) {:a "xxx"} a)

(defmacro info
  [& args]
  `(timbre/info ~@(scrub args)))
```

This doesnt work because scrub is called immediately and wont resolve symbols passed in.  I need something like either of these that dont work.

```
(defmacro info
  [& args]
  `(timbre/info @(scrub-log-pii ~args)))

(defmacro info
  [& args]
  `(timbre/info ~@('scrub-log-pii args)))
```

My last thought was to try to wrap the timbre macro in a function so the macro and evaluation happen in the right order.  There is however, no way to "apply" to a macro.

```
(defn info3
  [& args]
  (timbre/info (scrub-log-pii (vec args))))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have encountered a problem of using macros known as "turtles all the way down".  That is, instead of using function composition, you may need to write a wrapper macro, then another wrapper macro for that, etc.

The detailed steps to writing a macro are described in this answer:

- [How do I write a Clojure threading macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro)

For your specific problem, we could to this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

(defn infix-impl
  [a op b]
  (list op a b))

(defmacro infix
  "Allows user to have Java-style infix operators:

        (infix 2 + 3)
  "
  [a op b] (infix-impl a op b))

(defn infix-seq-impl
  [args]
  `(let [form#   (cons 'infix ~args)
         result# (eval form#)]
     result#))

(defmacro infix-seq
  [args] (infix-seq-impl args))

(dotest
  (is= 5 (infix 2 + 3))

  (let [params '[2 + 3]]
    (pp/pprint (infix-seq-impl 'params))

    (is= 5 (infix-seq params))))
```

Here we use the `infix` macro to show how to create a wrapper macro `infix-seq` that accepts a sequence of params instead of N scalar params.  The printed output shows the generated code:

```
(clojure.core/let
  [form__24889__auto__    (clojure.core/cons 'tst.demo.core/infix params)
   result__24890__auto__  (clojure.core/eval form__24889__auto__)]
 result__24890__auto__)
```

---

**A more general version**

The `applied` macro below allows you to pass in the name of the macro to be "applied" to the param sequence:

```
(defn applied-impl
  [f args]
  `(let [form#   (cons ~f ~args)
         result# (eval form#)]
     result#))

(defmacro applied 
  [f args] (applied-impl f args))

(dotest
  (nl)
  (let [params '[2 + 3]]
    ;      (applied 'infix params)   ; using a single quote fails
    (is= 5 (applied `infix params)) ; using a backquote works
    (is= 5 (applied 'tst.demo.core/infix params)) ; can also use fully-qualified symbol with single-quote
    (is= 5 (applied (quote tst.demo.core/infix) params)) ; single-quote is a "reader macro" for (quote ...)
    ))
```

Comment: This `apply-macro` only works if you have the arguments as separate literals already. There's no reason to write `(apply-macro foo [x y z])` when you could instead just write `(foo x y z)`. And it doesn't help with `(foo (make-xyz))`, because `(apply-macro foo (make-xyz))` also can't possibly know how many items are returned by that function call.

Comment: Good point; I didn't think it through. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Right, eval is required if you're going to do trickery like the question asks for, which is why it's generally not a thing you want to do. Your current solution is probably the closest one can get.

Comment: This solution doesnt help since I cant redefine all of the inputs to be literals. In my case, if I need to touch every call to the macro to change to string literal, there are simpler forms I can migrate to.  The messy marco stuff is to avoid redefining 2k legacy calls to log.

Comment: `params` is any Clojure sequence (list, vector, seq, lazy-seq, etc). The macro `applied` has no knowledge of what is in the seq. That why it needs to use `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

not exactly an answer to the question as phrased (macro application stuff), but rather the practical `timbre` solution, that may be applicable in your specific case:

[here](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/blob/master/src/taoensso/timbre.cljc#L780) you can see that all timbre macros use `log!` macro, which in turn accepts the collection of args.

so, just implementing your procedure as

```
(defmacro info* [args] `(log! :info :p ~args ~{:?line (fline &form)}))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: In particular, the [docstring for `log!`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/blob/master/src/taoensso/timbre.cljc#L706-L709) gives this example as well.

Comment: I did look at that.  fline is a private function so I stopped. Im now realizing that meta data is optional.

Comment: I tried again and im still having issues with the arg forms while applying changes.  Thanks for the suggestion.