# Is there a second undocumented evaluation phase for the &env macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

This macro  returns the values of the "magic" `&env` as a map, so that
`(let [xyz "ZYX"] (get-env))` returns `{xyz "ZYX"}`, where the key is a Symbol.

```clj
(defmacro get-env []
   (let [ks (keys &env)]
     `(zipmap '~ks [~@ks])))
```

The expression `'~ks` evaluates the `ks` into Symbols at the macro-expansion phase  (right?), but then quotes the expansion, so that the Symbols don't get evaluated into their values (`"ZYX"` in our example), but rather stay as Symbols (`xyz`). Is that right?

About `[~@ks]`: It evaluates `ks` into an seq of Symbols at the macro-expansion phase (right?) (and splices them and  forms a vector with `[]`). But how does that allow these Symbols to get further evaluated  into their values (`"ZYX"` in our example) -- is there a *second* evaluation step, applied immediately after the first?

Another variant is

```clj
(defmacro local-env [] (->> (keys &env)
  (map (fn [k] [(list 'quote k) k])) (into {})))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro takes all the keys from the env.  Then it uses the keys (a
list of symbols) to zip both the list of keys with spliced symbols
inside a vector.  So what you get from

```
(let [x 42]
  (get-env))
```

is

```
(let [x 42]
  (zipmap '(x) [x]))
```

This is a compile-time transformation of your code (the whole point of
macros).  The resulting code at runtime will use the 42 from the bound
x.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

You may also be interested in the book "Clojure Macros", and in this StackOverflow question:

[How do I write a Clojure threading macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro)

---

### Discussion

When in doubt, ask the compiler. Consider this code using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defmacro getenv []
  (prn :env &env)
  (prn :env-meta (meta &env))
  (prn :form &form)
  (prn :form-meta (meta &form)))

(defn go []
  (newline)
  (prn :01)
  (getenv)

  (let [x 1
        y "yyy"]
    (newline)
    (prn :02)
    (getenv))
  )

(dotest
  (go))
```

with output

```
:env nil
:env-meta nil
:form (getenv)
:form-meta {:line 15, :column 3}

:env {x #object[clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding 0x1ab07559 "clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding@1ab07559"], y #object[clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding 0x26c79134 "clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding@26c79134"]}
:env-meta nil
:form (getenv)
:form-meta {:line 21, :column 5}

Testing tst.demo.core

:01

:02
```

so we can see the 4 `(prn ...)` outputs for each call to `getenv`.  In the case where there are no local bindings, we get

```
&env ;=> nil
```

and for the case with the `let` we get a map like

```
  (let [env-val (quote
                  {x :compiler-local-1
                   y :compiler-local-1})
        ks      (keys env-val)
        ks-vec  [ks]
        ]
    (spyx env-val)
    (spyx ks)
    (spyx ks-vec)
    )
```

with result

```
env-val => {x :compiler-local-1, y :compiler-local-1}
ks      => (x y)
ks-vec  => [(x y)]
```

At this point, I'm not quite sure what your desired result is. Could you modify the question to add that?

BTW, there is no hidden 2nd step, if I understand your question correctly.

---

### Also

I rewrite your `local-env` and got the following result:

```
(defmacro local-env []
  (prn :into-result
    (into {}
      (mapv
        (fn [k] [(list 'quote k) k])
        (keys &env)))))

(let [x 1
      y "yyy"]
  (newline)
  (prn :03)
  (local-env))
```

with result

```
:into-result {(quote x) x, 
              (quote y) y}
```

so I think there is some confusion here.