# Understanding symbol resolution with macros in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm learning macros in clojure. I need help with symbol resolution in macros.

```
(ns macros.testing)

(def no (rand-int 10))

(defmacro drawer []
  `(do
     ~@(for [i (range no)]
     `(print ~i))))

(drawer) ;; This can resolve the global variable `no` properly


(defmacro drawer-2 [n]
  `(do
     ~@(for [i (range n)]
     `(print ~i))))


(drawer-2 10) ;; This works fine too
(drawer-2 n)  ;; This is not working, I'm unable to pass the global variable as an argument to the macro, although it's visible in the other case
```

The error message is `class clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.Symbol is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`.

Why clojure is unable to resolve the global variable in the second case and why can it do so for the first macro?

Comment: Please also see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212576/how-do-i-write-a-clojure-threading-macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a macro is evaluated, its arguments are passed "as is", without symbol resolution, as if they're all quoted. So if you pass `n`, within a macro it'll be a symbol `n` and not a value contained in a relevant var. If you pass `(inc 10)`, it'll be `'(inc 10)`. And so on.

So in `drawer`, `(range no)` works because `no` refers to a var that's bound to the result of `(rand-int 10)`.

In `drawer-2`, the argument `n` has the value of `(symbol "n")` (or just `'n`) during macro evaluation. And `(range 'n)` can't work - that's exactly what that "can't cast a symbol to a number" exception that you saw is about.

To fix that, you can explicitly resolve the passed symbol by using `resolve` (that `@` is needed to get the value of the resolved var):

```clj
(def value 10)

(defmacro drawer-2 [n]
  (let [n (if (symbol? n)
            @(resolve n)
            n)]
    `(do
       ~@(for [i (range n)]
           `(print ~i)))))

(drawer-2 value)
```